# How to parse received string into json in ios

Tags: ios, json

I have implemented XMPP in my ios app whenever somebody sends a message it receives an xml data and i'm getting message from that xml and making string of that.

```
NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
```

now *body contains json string and i'm parsing this string to json object using this line

```
NSData *data = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// messageJSON is NSDictionary
messageJSON=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

it is working well in condition of normal text but whenever anybody sends new line in the middle of the message it gives null please solve my problem.. :-(

Thanks in advance

OUTPUT

```
{"message":{"msg_type":"chat_success","msg_content":{"chat_id":"2","chat_message":"@34%*:%:%;%





Fjfjfjj","sender_id":"24","chat_date_time":"1413538998"}}
```

ERROR

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unescaped control character around character 94.) UserInfo=0x7fdf81c3a790 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 94.}
```

Comment: So it fails whenever invalid JSON is provided?  Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: So -- dump the input and see what's happening around character 94.

Comment: Please display what the string looks like in cases with, and without a newline.

Comment: But in other languages like php and all there is a function which parse array to json whether it includes new line character or not without any problem in the same way there may be any json parsing system in ios which converts new line character ("\n") to "\\n" which will escape the new line character.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization will skip over ordinary "whitespace" characters (including newlines) BETWEEN TOKENS with no difficulty.  There are some other characters there.  (Hint:  NSLog the NSData object -- it will dump in hex and you can examine the actual codes.)

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.

Comment: HotLicks@@ it skips new line from starting and end of the json but when anybody sends new line in middle of a message then it gives error and shows null.

Comment: This question cannot be answered; if the server (or whatever it is) is sending invalid JSON then the bug lies there, not in your code.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization will skip over ordinary "whitespace" characters (including newlines) **BETWEEN TOKENS** with no difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem comes from the conversion of XML <--> JSON.

in XML, carriage returns and line feeds are valid characters, (ignored mostly in favor of `<p>` and `<br/>`).  In JSON, the carriage return/line feed should be represented by a `\n` (or system appropriate)

I'm not sure if this will help, but try replacing any `\n` in your string with a `\\n` before Serializing it.